# Retire unused tags?

Tags: bug, tags

Several tags were created in the past few days and have no questions:
https://or.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new

I suspect these were created in error.  For example, see optimi.

Also, do we really need the lambert-w and wright-omega tags?

Answer (score 2):

We can just remove the tags from the questions: whether those that have been created by mistake (like `optimi`) or tags that don't add much value (like `time` tag). Based on [this meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags) post, tags with no questions will be deleted automatically.

Comment: Hmm, this raises two issues: 1. The unused ones are not getting automatically deleted at 3:00 UTC daily. 2. Some of these tags claim to have questions, but when you click on them, no questions are returned.

Comment: I removed `notation`  and `optimi` tag from questions to test that idea. This morning when I clicked on the link in your question, those two were no longer there.

Comment: OK, so maybe the second issue makes it look like the first issue occurs.  I see that both [lambert-w] and [wright-omega] are used in this question, but clicking on the tag yields no questions: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/298/usages-of-logarithmic-mean-in-optimization